# How to install Android studio in Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I am new in Android Studio and i am trying to install it in Ubuntu. I used these commands one after another.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

it installed correctly, but i am not able to start the Studio. How can i start it? Please help, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just download the zip file from

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

extract and run `studio.sh`

Answer (score 0):

follow this steps

Step 1: Open a terminal using the Dash or pressing Ctrl + Alt + T keys.
Step 2: If you have not, add that repository with the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: paolorotolo / android-studio
```

Step 3: Update the APT with the command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 4: Now install the program with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

Step 5: Once installed, run the program by typing in Dash:

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

if all done

**step1:** find **studio.sh** file like this:location:**/computer/opt/abdriud-studio/bin/studio.sh**

[image: file location]

**step2:**open terminal(CTRL+ALT+T) write down command and enter
[image: command line]

Answer (score 0):

open the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

**step1**:
        sudo apt update

```
    sudo apt install android-sdk
```

**step2**:go to the browser Download the software from [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio)

after extract the Android studio.tar.gz  file

**step3**: Go to this folder's directory using **cd /home/(USER NAME)/android-studio/bin/**

```
          example:cd /home/pr4v33n/Downloads/android-studio/bin/
```

**step4**:Type this command to make studio.sh executable: 
            **chmod +x studio.sh**

**step5**: type the command **./studio.sh**

**step6**:A pop up will be shown asking for installation pop up will be shown asking for installation settings. In my particular case, it is a fresh install so I'll go with selecting I do not have a previous version of Studio or I do not want to import my settings.

**step7**:after select the standard setup  android studio version

**step8**:start the project